# Slow ui response when showing lot of images at once

Tags: html, css, performance

Let's say I have two sibling divs that shouldn't be showed at the same time. Inside both divs there are about 50 images.

Div 1 is showed by default with the class "active". But when the user clicks a certain button, it triggers an event that remove class "active" from Div 1 and append it to Div 2.

This toggle of divs works fine on a pc, but on some mobile devices, the response is TOO slow.

This is what I've tried so far:

First attempt:

```
div {
    display: none;
    &.active {
        display: block;
    }
    img { display: block; /* always */ }
}
```

Second attempt:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 9999px; // in a viewport far far away
    &.active {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
    }
    img { display: block; /* always */ }
}
```

Regardless the device specifications, I'm sure there must be a way to get the better performance on ALL devices. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: What file type/average size are your images? Might also give a shot with visibility:hidden.

Comment: Aside from using [mobile-optimized images](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/serving-responsive-images/), you should look into [lazy loading images](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/lazy-loading-images-on-the-web/) for better performance as well.

Comment: @shamsup images are already loaded

Comment: @chris-w will try and update my question

Comment: If they're png/jpg, I hope you're at least throwing them through compression like [tinyPNG](http://tinypng.com) to cut their size in half.

Comment: Images can't be compressed any more (already batched on fireworks). They are pngs, total size of all images = 1.5 mb (visibility dind't work)

Comment: I still run images through even after saving the mobile version from adobe products and cut their sizes down without losing quality. However 1.5mb isn't bad for 50 images. If that's still an issue, I'd consider grouping them into a sprite and using that method instead of toggling DOM objects. If you're using like sass/compass it's much easier to do.